# Checking for first and last panel arguments in a variant selection rule

Tags: panels

I am creating a panel page in Drupal 7. My original idea is ending having urls following the next structure:

problem/!nid/!topicname/!level.

The "topicname" and "level" arguments are both taxonomy term names and "nid" is the nid :-).

As you can see, all the arguments are optional. My question comes with selection rules. Is there a way for having a variant displayed when first ("nid") and last argument ("level") are presents?

This means "problem/32/advance" would be a panel variant. I've been making some test and when I add a "context exist" selection rule it doesn't select the corresponding variant, it just shows the "default variant" (the last in the variant list order).

Hope everything makes sense. If you need further information, just let me know please.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.